# Transitioning from one view/template to another in Ember.js rc1

Tags: ember.js

In the "new" Ember.js (post Feb 15 2013), the old routes and transitions no longer work. I'm trying to figure out how to replace them. I've created [a super-simple jdfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayoung/RLmPk/9/) to illustrate what I currently have.

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  <li><a {{action editDetails item}}> {{item.title}} </a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Each item has an ID, and this is successfully passed to editDetails() on the IndexController (click on one of the three hard-coded items in the output):

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  editDetails: function(params){
    console.log('details! ' + params.id);
  }
});
```

Another template is waiting for a controller to show it and hand it the item for the details.... but nothing I have tried from this point works. So, how do I get these two hooked up together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated your [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/durinthomas/RLmPk/11/).

`{{action}}` helper are no longer used to transitioning between routes.

Now you must use the `{{#linkTo}}` helper.

```html
{{#each item in controller}}
    <li>{{#linkTo 'editDetails' item}}{{item.title}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Please take a look to the [`emberjs guides`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/)